# How to correctly pipe commands in Cygwin (Using Windows)?

Tags: windows, cmd, cygwin, pipeline

I'm trying to run experiments on a text file to get word frequencies. I tried using the following command:

```
gawk -F"[ ,'\".]" -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) words[$i]++;}END{for (i in words) print words[i]" "i}' myfile.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -10
```

But I get the following error:

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file '|' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I read somewhere that ';' may be used instead of '|' on Windows machines, although this results in a similar error.

It seems as though it is reading the first instance of '|' as a file name. Is this the correct way of piping on a windows machine? Is piping possible on a windows machine using Cygwin?

EDIT: I added cygwin to windows PATH variable and then used cmd window. If i wanted to actually use cygwin.exe, does that mean I would have to place any files I wanted to edit within C:/cygwin ?

Comment: I think you need to run in Bash and not cmd. I do not have Windows to test.

Comment: Edit your question to clearly state if you are executing your commands in a Cygwin shell window or in a Windows cmd window. If the former then the error you are getting is inexplicable. If the latter - don't do that!

Comment: @Ed Morton Thanks, check my edit.

Comment: You can use `cygdrive` to access Windows directories within Cygwin.

Comment: Depending on your other needs, you might be better off with native ports of standard UNIX tools, e.g., MSYS, MinGW, Gnuwin32, which are designed for use with the standard Windows command line.  Cygwin *may* be overpowered for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I understand - don't do that! Execute cygwin commands from cygwin, not from Windows. To execute a cygwin command on any file, just give the command the full path to the file (but starting with `/cygdrive/`), it doesn't have to be under `C:/cygwin`, e.g. from a cygwin shell window to see what's in the common Windows folder `C:\Documents and Settings`:

```
$ ls -Q '/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings'
"All Users"  "Default"  "Default User"  "desktop.ini"  "emorton" etc...
```